# Xamarin application access LAMP server on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: iphone, xamarin, raspberry-pi, lamp

I'm currently making my first steps into developing a basic iPhone app and want it to retrieve information from a raspberry Pi set up as a server and send a push alert to the app user. The process should look something like this:

1. Daily list of Flavours added to Pi (which is set up as a server using LAMP)
2. iPhone app (designed/built using Xamarin) retrieves list of flavours from the server
3. Push notification sent based on user defined 'favourite flavours'

At this stage I'm trying to keep the app as simple as possible in that the users only need to select their favourite flavours from a full list and the app will retrieve and compare their list against the source list giving them a notification if any of their favourites are available.

I realise this is quite an open ended question. What I'm really looking for is any ideas if this process sounds feasible, possible flaws in my understanding, any interaction issues between the pi server the app and if people think that a Pi would be able to handle this functionality.

Comment: Big question. A brief answer is there should be no problem retrieving data from a Ras-Pi server, or any server, as long as you expose a REST API to get what you need. Whether a ras-pi can handle it depends on how many requests you anticipate. I could see a ras-pi quickly getting over loaded. I am going to flag this as too broad a question as it involves networking, bandwidth, servers, push notifications, etc.